# SSL certificate from letsencrypt not securing (nginx/ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have created SSL certificate from lets-encrypt using certbot application

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates

And configured my nginx server with ssl cert and key but when i access website with https it still insecure.

furthermore i have checked my website with ssl labs it returns an overall rating C with  a warning  in cipher strength

This server uses RC4 with modern protocols. Grade capped to C.

**update**
Domain name

https://cushbu.com

Comment: Please edit your configuration in the question. The actual domain name can also be helpful in the diagnosis.

Comment: Additionally the browser typically says why it views it as insecure. For instance chrome will say NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID if the name in the certificate does not match the hostname.

Comment: Let me edit the question

Comment: Can't see any specific error message in chrome

Comment: According to my Chrome there is nothing wrong with your certificates. It only criticizes that some resources (styleheets, script files) are loaded via http instead of https.

Comment: It's the problem of base URL it will be fixed soon but why the connection is not secured error message is shown .

Answer (score 1):

Its because mixed content problem

check in dev tools

```
Mixed content
The site includes HTTP resources.

Reload the page to record requests for HTTP resources.
```

So fix your app, if u have a cross domain images, login form and etc. (as example)

Comment: Yes. He is right. Go to this for instance: https://cushbu.com/images/img3.jpg

Some one probably has incorrectly formed redirects in JS or HTML, which hard coded "http" - my guess

Comment: So all the assets should be served from HTTPS instead of http??

Comment: yes. make reindex of all your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling RC4 and use AES. RC4 has been deemed insecure by major browser vendors (google, mozilla, microsoft) as of sometime in 2016.

Comment: How to disable RC4